# Get HttpContext.Current with aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="false" in wcf service

Tags: asp.net, wcf, https, web-config, httpcontext

My website is completely HTTPS. So I want to call the WCFService in HTTPS protocol but Microsoft says with `aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"` we can not use non-http bindings, may be that is why I am getting ServiceActionException.
When I make `aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="false"` WCF service is working fine HTTPS. But the value of `HttpContext.Current` is **null**.

So how can I get the HttpContext.Current value with HTTPS binding?

I am following this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa702682(v=vs.110).aspx)

Can anyone help please?

Comment: what binding are you using?

Answer (score 0):

for HttpContext.Current to be a non-null value you have to have aspNetCompatibility set to true or allowed. You can access the message headers via WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest.Headers.